# How to convert this create store with thunk to a promise based?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

My app is originally loading data from local-storage, Now i am trying to use firebase.
Firebase always tend to return a promise. So I am trying to convert the store into firebase return one.

here is the original one

```
export const loadState = () => {
  const state: AppState = getDefaultState();
  VALID_LABS.forEach(labId => {
    state.labs[labId] = getDefaultLabState();
    STORAGE_CONFIG.forEach(storageField => {
      const { statePath, storageKey, defaultValueFn } = storageField;
      const loadedValue = getFromLocalStorage(
        labId,
        storageKey,
        defaultValueFn()
      );
      cachedValues[`${labId}:${storageKey}`] = loadedValue;
      set(state, `labs.${labId}.${statePath}`, loadedValue);
    });
  });
  return state as AppState;
};
```

---

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, loadState(), applyMiddleware(thunk));
store.subscribe(
  throttle(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
  }, 500)
);
```

as you can see i am making process working fine. But the problem arise when i start using firebase.

my loadState become something like this.

```
export const loadState = (): AppState => {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/' + userId)
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val() as AppState;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }
};
```

So I also need to convert the `store` to accept the `promise` returning from the new `loadState`.
I don't know how to convert it since I am also using `applyMiddleWare(thunk)`

```
let saveState: (state: AppState) => void     ;
let loadState: () => AppState;
if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
  loadState = loadStateFirebase;
  saveState = saveStateFirebase;
}else{
  loadState = loadStateLocalStorage;
  saveState = saveStateLocalStorage;
}

// call loadstate then data,pass it in as second para to appstate store
const store = createStore(rootReducer, loadState(), applyMiddleware(thunk));
store.subscribe(
  throttle(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
  }, 500)
);


const reactReduxFirebaseProps = {
  firebase,
  config: {},
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AmplitudeProvider {...amplitudeProps}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...reactReduxFirebaseProps}>
        <Router>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </AmplitudeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

Then thunk middleware works only for the actions. So basically a middleware takes all the actions and returns the computed new state. This is not related to the `createStore` function.
The store creation process, in general, is a synchronous method.

But You can pass a default `store` object for your `Provider` and after this, when the async firebase call comes back, you can reinitialize the entire state.
I think you can do better. Simply dispatch an action when your `App.js` does the component `onInit` life-cycle. And in a thunk action do the logic.
For example:

```js
//--- rest of the app.js

  useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(getUser())
  } , [dispatch]);
  
// --- do the initialization only once, when the component loads


//--- the action

export const getUser = createAsyncThunk('GET_USER', async () => {
 if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const snapshot = await firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/' + userId)
      .once('value');
    return snapshot.val() as AppState;
  } else {
    throw Erro('NO LOGGED IN USER!');
  }
})
```

You can import this action in your reducer, and you can get the values like this:

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch(action.type){
      case getUser.fulfilled:

      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

make your loadState function return type Promise

```
export const loadState = (): Promise<AppState> => {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/' + userId)
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val() as AppState;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }
};
```

and when you want to use it then

```
loadState().then(function (appstate){
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, appstate, applyMiddleware(thunk));
        store.subscribe(
          throttle(() => {
            saveState(store.getState());
          }, 500)
        );
})
```

Comment: Ty for answering. When I change the code according to your answer.
I am getting this error `Cannot find name 'store'`  Is that because we are delcaring store inside a anonymous function?

Comment: it doesn't make sense. store is undefined can make sense but cannot find store doesn't make sense. Try to check the brackets.

Comment: ? Isn't declaring `function (appstate:any) {const  store = ...`make the store available only inside this function right?

Comment: yes, it will make store available only in that function. If you are accessing it out of the function then it will fail. Also try to write all of your code inside that function because it is async, so if you write code outside of function then, there is a great possibility that store may not be initialized.

Comment: So One last thing, Ty for your patient. Can you review my question one more time.
There are 2 more cases where I  use store `store.dispatch`  & inside the render 
`<Provider store={store}>` . What your suggestion is that i write those inside the function?

Comment: sure, Yes you have to write that inside the function. but I am no React expert though. but it should work.